# Forwarding messages to other Akka actors

Tags: scala, akka

Scala 2.12 using Akka here. When one of my actors receives a particular type of message (say, `Fizzbuzz`), I want it to forward that message on to a small number of other actors, exactly as-is:

I tried:

```
class Foo extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Bar =>
      println("Bar!")
    case Whitstle =>
      println("Whistle!")
    case Fizzbuzz =>
      val actor1 = context.actorSelection("/user/a1")
      val actor2 = context.actorSelection("/user/a2")
      val actor3 = context.actorSelection("/user/a3")

      actor1 ! _
      actor2 ! _
      actor3 ! _
  }
}
```

And while that compiles and doesn't throw any exceptions, it doesn't work (none of the 3 actors ever receive the `Fizzbuzz` message). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the receive block, collect your msg in a variable and then forward that msg to other actors. Please refer the code below :-

```
class Foo extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Bar =>
      println("Bar!")
    case Whitstle =>
      println("Whistle!")
    case msg : Fizzbuzz =>
      val actor1 = context.actorSelection("/user/a1")
      val actor2 = context.actorSelection("/user/a2")
      val actor3 = context.actorSelection("/user/a3")

      actor1 ! msg 
      actor2 ! msg 
      actor3 ! msg 
  }
}
```

This should solve your problem. Please let me know if any doubt persists.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup can you please try this approach.